# How to Map values in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am confused with reactjs api json call back.

In my container>> i have an api response from this -->  let broadcast = this.props.broadcastDetailsPageApiResponse;

I need to map the values to 'broadcastData' variable to print it in component page html.(fileds like 'channel','description','recordedUrl',

How can i do it?

The api response as follows.

broadcastdetailcontainer.jsx: place to map console.log("need to map");line  no 34.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import BroadcastDetailPage from '../components/broadcastList/broadcastDetailPage.jsx'
import * as detailPageActions from '../actions/detailPageActions.jsx'

class BroadcastDetailContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {broadcastData: {}};
        this.updateBroadcastData = this.updateBroadcastData.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let broadcastId = this.props.params.broadcastId;
         console.log("Broadcast Id in the componentDidMount: " + broadcastId);
        this.updateBroadcastData(broadcastId);
    }


    updateBroadcastData(broadcastId) {
        let broadcastData;
        let broadcast = this.props.broadcastDetailsPageApiResponse;
       // console.log("broadcast: " + JSON.stringify(broadcast));

        if (broadcast != null) {


 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

               broadcastData = broadcast.channel;
               broadcastData = broadcast.user;

            console.log("need to map");
            //console.log(broadcastData);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

        let content = this.props.homePageApiResponse.content;
        if (content != null & broadcastData == null) {
            console.log('entered when the home API');
            for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                if (content[i].id == broadcastId) {
                    broadcastData = content[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (broadcastData == null) {
            content = this.props.searchPageApiResponse.content;
            if (content != null) {
                console.log('entered when the search API');
                for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                    if (content[i].id == broadcastId) {
                        broadcastData = content[i];
                        console.log(broadcastData);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (broadcastData == null) {
            this.props.actions.callDetailApi(broadcastId);
        }
        else{
            this.setState({broadcastData: broadcastData});
        }

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        let broadcastId = nextProps.params.broadcastId;
        console.log('componentWillReceiveProps');
        this.updateBroadcastData(broadcastId);
    }


    render() {
        //console.log("rendered: "+JSON.stringify(this.props.broadcastDetailsPageApiResponse));
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.broadcastData &&
                <BroadcastDetailPage
                    broadcastDetail={this.state.broadcastData}/>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    homePageApiResponse: state.homePageApiResponse,
    searchPageApiResponse: state.searchPageApiResponse,
    broadcastDetailsPageApiResponse: state.detailPageApiResponse,
})

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(detailPageActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)
(BroadcastDetailContainer)
```

I need to display the map values in the following component page:

```
import React, {Component} from "React";
import {Row, Clearfix} from "react-bootstrap/lib";
import VideoPlayer from "./videoPlayer.jsx";

class BroadcastDetailPage extends Component {
    render() {
        let broadcastData = this.props.broadcastDetail;

        return (
            <Row>
                <div className="popup-cont-container">
                    <VideoPlayer broadcastData={broadcastData}/>
                    <div className="video-info">
                        <div className="info-left">
                            <div className="main-tag">
                                <a href="#"># {broadcastData.channel} </a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="datenTime">
                                On Date
                            </div>
                            <div className="datenTime"> Location
                            </div>
                            <div className="video-info-main"> </div>
                            <div className="at">@
                              <a href="#">{broadcastData.handle} </a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="info-right">
                            <span><img src="images/eyeico.png"/>
                                <a>   </a> Live viewers
                            </span>
                            <span><img src="images/heart.png"/>
                                <a>   </a> Likes
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Clearfix/>
                </div>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}
export default BroadcastDetailPage





 {"id":4,"user":{"userId":1,"chatUserId":0,"handle":"satishkrypto","countryCode":"+971","phone":"569942359","picUrl":"https://ss-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/production-speakerswire-images/user-profiles/male3x.png","userStat":{"id":1,"followers":4,"followings":5,"broadcastLikes":0,"broadcastViews":90},"name":"satish verma","existingUser":false,"userProfileImageType":"MALE","invitesLeft":4,"userPriviledge":"SW_BROADCASTER"},"description":"satish's Broadcast","streamId":"pub11489928734882","audio":false,"screenShotUrl":"https://ss-api-eb-dev.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/broadcast-images/pub11489928734882-1489928751454.jpg","recordedUrl":"https://production-ss-videos-red5pro.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/video/record/pub581489997130311.mp4","status":"RECORDED","type":"PUBLIC","locationEnabled":false,"commentsEnabled":true,"channel":{"channelId":14,"channel":"Productivity","color":"#4A148C","priority":986,"created":1489922543000,"updated":1489922543000,"broadcast":0,"liveBroadcast":0},"broadcastStat":{"id":4,"likes":0,"views":14,"viewers":5,"liveViewers":0},"latitude":0.0,"longitude":0.0,"startTime":1489928737000,"endTime":1489928787000,"updated":1489928737000,"event":{"id":4,"description":"satish's Broadcast","type":"BROADCAST_PUBLIC","startTime":1489928737000,"endTime":1489928787000,"status":"FINISHED","eventReminderStatus":"NOT_SENT","updatedAt":1489928787000},"expectedDuration":0,"serviceProvider":"agora"}
```

Update:

```
broadcastData = {
                    ...broadcast,
                    broadcaster: {
                        name: broadcast.user.name,
                        handle: broadcast.user.handle
                    },
                    channel: {
                       // channelName: broadcast.channel
                    },
                    likes: broadcast.broadcastStat.likes,
                    views: broadcast.broadcastStat.views,
                }
```

Comment: response that u attached, is not in a proper `json` format. edit the ques with proper `json`, or attach the screenshot of result of `console.log()`

Comment: This doesn't sound like a React-related problem at all. It sort of sounds like you can't be bothered with writing the function out yourself so you're asking someone else to do it for you.

Comment: i updated the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values that you specified in ques, are present directly inside `object`, you can access them by `data.channel.any_key, data.description, data.recordedUrl`.

If you want to print all the values of `data.channel`, then use map otherwise you can access directly by `data.channel.channel`.

Check this example:

```js
let data = {
     "id":4,
     "user":{
      "userId":1,
      "chatUserId":0,
      "handle":"satishkrypto",
      "countryCode":"+971",
      "phone":"569942359",
      "picUrl":"https://ss-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/production-speakerswire-images/user-profiles/male3x.png",
      "userStat":{
       "id":1,
       "followers":4,
       "followings":5,
       "broadcastLikes":0,
       "broadcastViews":90
      },
      "name":"satish verma",
      "existingUser":false,
      "userProfileImageType":"MALE",
      "invitesLeft":4,
      "userPriviledge":"SW_BROADCASTER"
     },
     "description":"satish's Broadcast",
     "streamId":"pub11489928734882",
     "audio":false,
     "screenShotUrl":"https://ss-api-eb-dev.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/broadcast-images/pub11489928734882-1489928751454.jpg",
     "recordedUrl":"https://production-ss-videos-red5pro.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/video/record/pub581489997130311.mp4",
     "status":"RECORDED",
     "type":"PUBLIC",
     "locationEnabled":false,
     "commentsEnabled":true,
     "channel":{
      "channelId":14,
      "channel":"Productivity",
      "color":"#4A148C",
      "priority":986,
      "created":1489922543000,
      "updated":1489922543000,
      "broadcast":0,"liveBroadcast":0
     },
     "broadcastStat":{
      "id":4,
      "likes":0,
      "views":14,
      "viewers":5,
      "liveViewers":0
     },
     "latitude":0.0,
     "longitude":0.0,
     "startTime":1489928737000,
     "endTime":1489928787000,
     "updated":1489928737000,
     "event":{
      "id":4,
      "description":"satish's Broadcast",
      "type":"BROADCAST_PUBLIC",
      "startTime":1489928737000,
      "endTime":1489928787000,
      "status":"FINISHED",
      "eventReminderStatus":"NOT_SENT",
      "updatedAt":1489928787000
     },
     "expectedDuration":0,
     "serviceProvider":"agora"
    };
    
class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return(
         <div>
          Channel Details: {Object.keys(data.channel).map(el=>{
                return <p>{el}: {data.channel[el]}</p>
          })}
          Description: {data.description}
          RecordedUrl: {data.recordedUrl}
         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: @gitu use it in the same way as i specified in example, it will work on 2nd page also, just you need to change the name of variable, i used `data` and u defined as  `let broadcastData = this.props.broadcastDetail;`, use `broadcastData`, use the same code on 2nd page.  let me know if it throws any error :)

Comment: i use  let broadcast = this.props.broadcastDetailsPageApiResponse;
        broadcastData = broadcast;  in first page and tried the below in 2nd {broadcastData.channel}   shows error "error in detail page api call Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {channelId, channel, color, priority, created, updated, broadcast, liveBroadcast}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons."

Comment: because channel is an object, and we can not directly print then in JSX, use map like i used in example, or specify the value that u want to access like, `{broadcastData.channel.channel}`.

Comment: still facing any issue ??

Comment: How to remove the error message "Warning: Automatically setting basename using <base href> is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release."

Comment: it looks like something related to browserhistory, check these links: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3387  and https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4055 this issue is already reported on github.

Answer (score 1):

Component 1

```
 render() {
        return (

            <div className="flexslider tabs_slider no-slide">
                <ul className="slides">

                    {this.state.Movies.map((item, index) => <Component2
                        key={item.db_recom_id}
                        item={item}
                    />)}

                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Component 2

```
 render() {

        return (
            <li>

                    <img className="wrap_me" src={this.props.item.db_movies_img} />
        )
    }
```